# File command Linux package name

Tags: linux, centos, fedora

I can't find out which package provides the `file` on CentOS 6.

Comment: Try `sudo yum install file`.

Comment: Use `sudo dnf install file`.

Answer (score 4):

If you had `file` installed on one of your systems, than the following command would have answered your question

```
 rpm -q --whatprovides `which file`
```

In CentOS and other RedHat derived distributions the name of the package is `file`

```
 $ rpm -q --whatprovides `which file`
 file-5.04-13.el6.x86_64
```

**Edit 2** (after a comment from jww)

To install `file` type

```
 sudo yum install file
```

**Edit 1** As @Miquel reminds in Debian and Ubuntu one can use `dpkg-query -S`:

```
 $ dpkg-query -S `which file`
 file: /usr/bin/file
```

Comment: Replace `rpm -q` with `dpkg -S` in debian/ubuntu/derivates

Comment: The `file` progam is missing on CentOS 6 and 7: ***`/usr/bin/which: no file in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)`*** I don't believe we can use `which` to locate it. And `rpm -q --whatprovides "/usr/bin/file"` results in ***`error: file /usr/bin/file: No such file or directory`***.

Comment: @jww edited the post